# Utility to Strip Comments from LaTeX Source

Tags: tools, comments

```
I've a LaTeX source.
I'm ready %for submission
%But first I would like
to strip its comments.

So I hope there are
100\% auto
ways to get this done.

\begin{comment}
   Because there are subtle ways to mess it up.
\end{comment}
```

Is there a utility which will eliminate all these comments?

Yes, I could do it by hand, but that seems needlessly laborious, has the potential for mistakes, and makes maintenance difficult. I could also use `sed`, but there's a potential for mistakes. Besides, it is an axiom of the whole GNU/Linux thing that if you can think of it, someone's probably already made a utility for it.

Comment: should the text "Because there ..." be printed?

Comment: No, it's in a comment environment from the `verbatim` package.

Comment: ah, I see, you want to delete the `%blabla ..`

Comment: you might want to try http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82972/delete-comments-in-tex-file-with-emacsauctex/82981#82981 but it would need extending for your examples:-)

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, alas, I am using the verbatim package, which is not covered by that answer and am not using emacs, so the script doesn't seem to be of direct benefit.

Comment: Related comment: some tex source editors (specifically TeXShop, but probably others as well) provide shortcuts for adding and removing `%` signs at the beginning of each line in a range. Using this might make the `comment` environment unnecessary, which would simplify the task.

Comment: Should the code also cope with constructs such as `\verb+%+` ?

Comment: Your request has no solution because percentage signs may be in verbatim environments with names that depend on user-included packages.

Comment: For motivation as to why one might want to do this, see https://twitter.com/overheardonaph

Comment: See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451849/64454) for using **regular expressions** (+ a step-by-step process detailing how to implement them in your IDE — even if it does not support regex lookaround).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To remove all the comments from a LaTeX file, one can use [arxiv-latex-cleaner](https://github.com/google-research/arxiv-latex-cleaner/). Actively maintained, 1.2k GitHub stars, Apache-2.0 license, written in Python but no need to know Python.

Example:

```
pip install arxiv-latex-cleaner
arxiv_latex_cleaner /path/to/latex_folder
```

Comment: Exactly. See what happens if you don't clean your .tex before uploading to arXiv: https://twitter.com/DV2559106965076/status/1638769434763608064

Comment: @a06e I've always wondered why arxiv doesn't an option to remove comments. Sounds rather obvious to me.

Comment: is there also a way to run it on a single file only?

Comment: @user313032 I don't think so, aside from moving that file in its own folder.

Comment: thanks, i'm using latexpand now (mentioned below)

Comment: is there a way to exclude unused if blocks depending on conditionals defined by \newif?

Comment: @user313032 sorry, no idea

Answer (score 49):

## [latexpand](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexpand)

(distributed with TeXLive)

`latexpand` is a tool to expand `include/input` directives which also removes comments. It can also be tweaked to keep end-of-line comments because sometimes they are meaningful. In a second step remove lines with only `%`:

```
$ latexpand --empty-comments mytexfile.tex > mytexfile-stripped.tex
```

Remove lines with only `%` and whitespace:

```sh
$ sed -i '/^\s*%/d' mytexfile-stripped.tex
```

and squeeze blank lines (`cat -s` might have problems with window line endings and on [os solaris](http://www.polarhome.com/service/man/?qf=cat&af=0&sf=0&of=Solaris&tf=2) `-s` has a different meaning)

```
$ cat -s mytexfile-stripped.tex | sponge mytexfile-stripped.tex
```

(`sponge` is part of `moreutils` from https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/)

Comment: But `latexpand` translates all includes into the included file.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian There is an option `--keep-includes`.

Comment: This is a very nice and handy solution! I have directly put it into a script, see my answer below, because it seems I cannot add code in a comment.

Comment: I was getting an "invalid command" message on OSX when I ran the above sed command. I changed sed to gsed and that fixed the problem.

Comment: Upvote from me because it is built-in texlive, no need for additional scripts.

Comment: I also was getting an "invalid command" message on OSX when I ran the above `sed` command. I changed `sed` to `gsed` and the `sed -i...` command worked beautifully. But to get `gsed` to run, I had to update Python using the `brew` commands outlined in `The Path to Homebrew` at `https://rkulla.blogspot.com/2014/03/the-path-to-homebrew.html`. For me, the `brew doctor` and `brew update` commands took well over 24 hours to complete. Patience...

Comment: sed -i '' -e "/^\s*%/d" main_striped.tex

Comment: is there a way to exclude unused if blocks depending on conditionals defined by \newif?

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure how to do this.  So, I'm posting a new solution.  The code I posted yesterday will eat comments from within a `verbatim` environment.

Here's a new example file to be cleaned:

```
I've a LaTeX source.
I'm ready %for submission
%But first I would like
to strip its comments.

So I hope there are
100\% auto
ways to get this done.

\begin{comment}
   Because there are subtle ways to mess it up.
\end{comment}

\begin{verbatim}
        next two lines should not be lost
        % don't lose this line
% this line should stay too
\end{verbatim}
```

According to the `verbatim` package documentation `verbatim` and `comment` environments should not be nested.  The following code (similar to what I posted yesterday) will not eat commented lines that appear within a `verbatim` environment.

Here is the corrected Perl code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict 'vars';
&MAIN(@ARGV);
sub MAIN {
   my ($filehandle) = @_;

   open FILE, "<$filehandle";
   my @doc = <FILE>;
   close FILE;

   &removeComments(\@doc);

   foreach my $line ( @doc ){
      print $line;
    }

   return 1;
}

sub removeComments {
   my ($docarray) = @_;

   my $isCommentEnvironment  = "no";
   my $isVerbatimEnvironment = "no";

   my @newdoc;

   foreach my $line ( @{$docarray} ){
      $isVerbatimEnvironment = "yes" if ( $line =~ /^\\begin{verbatim}/ );
      $isCommentEnvironment  = "yes" if ( $line =~ /^\\begin{comment}/ );
      if ( ($isVerbatimEnvironment eq "no") && ($isCommentEnvironment eq "no") ){
     next if ($line =~ /^%/);
     ## Temporarily replace "%" that you want to keep with a dummy string
     ## that does not appear elsewhere in your document.  Then, remove remainder
     ## of lines that still contain "%".
     if ( $line =~ /\\%/){
        $line =~ s/\\%/TMP::PERCENT/g;
        $line =~ s/%.*//;
        $line =~ s/TMP::PERCENT/\\%/g;
      } else {
     ## do not remove trailing % marking NO SPACE in LaTeX: $line =~ s/%.*//;
         $line =~ s/\s*%.+//;
       }
     push @newdoc, $line;
       }
      push @newdoc, $line if ( $isVerbatimEnvironment eq "yes" );

      $isVerbatimEnvironment = "no" if ( $line =~ /^\\end{verbatim}/ );
      $isCommentEnvironment  = "no" if ( $line =~ /^\\end{comment}/ );
    }

   @{$docarray} = @newdoc;
   return 1;
 }
```

Comment: I think the standard convention here on TeX.SX would be to add this as an alternative in the first solution you provide, by using the `edit` button.

Comment: How can I output the code shown in the console to a file?

Comment: Save the script to a file, let's call it `stripcomments.pl`.  And let's say the file you want to remove comments called is `mytext.tex`.  Then on the command line write, `perl stripcomments.pl mytext.tex > no_comment.tex`.  Just be careful.  Redirecting output this way will not warn you about overwriting an already existing file.

Comment: The code provided by A.Ellett worked great for me, with a notable exception: the '%' sign at the end of the line should not be removed, as they have the side-effect of "eating" the white space represented by the newline. As a consequence, I used a different regex for the substitution: `s/\s*%.+//`.

Comment: I think also the line `next if ($line =~ /^%/);` had better be `next if ($line =~ /^\s*%/);`, else the output will contain blank lines that aren't present in the original

Comment: I think the current version (with and without @D.Savitt hint) makes from `BLABLA%TEST` this `BLABLA`. It would be nice to have some option to get this `BLABLA%` i.e. to still prevent 'eating' the white space.

Comment: The edit suggested by @user1366204 should not only be used in the else part, but also between the TMP::PERCENT replacements.
I also opted for @D.Savitt edit, as I had some trouble with an indented comment inside a caption.
For the last comment and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212885/13657 , one option could be: 
remove % and anything that follows IFF there is a whitespace before:
`$line =~ s/\s+%.+//;`
In remaining cases (i.e. there is NO whitespace before), end line with a %:
`$line =~ s/%.+/%/;`
I just use both lines instead of building any if construct/optional matches.

Answer (score 11):

It can be done using the Python ply.lex module to write a simple tokenizer:

```python
import ply.lex, argparse, io

#Usage
# python stripcomments.py input.tex > output.tex
# python stripcomments.py input.tex -e encoding > output.tex

def strip_comments(source):
    tokens = (
                'PERCENT', 'BEGINCOMMENT', 'ENDCOMMENT', 'BACKSLASH',
                'CHAR', 'BEGINVERBATIM', 'ENDVERBATIM', 'NEWLINE', 'ESCPCT',
             )
    states = (
                ('linecomment', 'exclusive'), 
                ('commentenv', 'exclusive'), 
                ('verbatim', 'exclusive')
            )

    #Deal with escaped backslashes, so we don't think they're escaping %.
    def t_ANY_BACKSLASH(t):
        r"\\\\"
        return t

    #One-line comments
    def t_PERCENT(t):
        r"\%"
        t.lexer.begin("linecomment")

    #Escaped percent signs
    def t_ESCPCT(t):
        r"\\\%"
        return t

    #Comment environment, as defined by verbatim package       
    def t_BEGINCOMMENT(t):
        r"\\begin\s*{\s*comment\s*}"
        t.lexer.begin("commentenv")

    #Verbatim environment (different treatment of comments within)   
    def t_BEGINVERBATIM(t):
        r"\\begin\s*{\s*verbatim\s*}"
        t.lexer.begin("verbatim")
        return t

    #Any other character in initial state we leave alone    
    def t_CHAR(t):
        r"."
        return t

    def t_NEWLINE(t):
        r"\n"
        return t

    #End comment environment    
    def t_commentenv_ENDCOMMENT(t):
        r"\\end\s*{\s*comment\s*}"
        #Anything after \end{comment} on a line is ignored!
        t.lexer.begin('linecomment')

    #Ignore comments of comment environment    
    def t_commentenv_CHAR(t):
        r"."
        pass

    def t_commentenv_NEWLINE(t):
        r"\n"
        pass

    #End of verbatim environment    
    def t_verbatim_ENDVERBATIM(t):
        r"\\end\s*{\s*verbatim\s*}"
        t.lexer.begin('INITIAL')
        return t

    #Leave contents of verbatim environment alone
    def t_verbatim_CHAR(t):
        r"."
        return t

    def t_verbatim_NEWLINE(t):
        r"\n"
        return t

    #End a % comment when we get to a new line
    def t_linecomment_ENDCOMMENT(t):
        r"\n"
        t.lexer.begin("INITIAL")
        #Newline at the end of a line comment is stripped.

    #Ignore anything after a % on a line        
    def t_linecomment_CHAR(t):
        r"."
        pass

    lexer = ply.lex.lex()
    lexer.input(source)
    return u"".join([tok.value for tok in lexer])

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('filename', help = 'the file to strip comments from')
    parser.add_argument('--encoding', '-e', default='utf-8')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    with io.open(args.filename, encoding=args.encoding) as f:
        source = f.read()

    print(strip_comments(source))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Alternately, here is a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/amerberg/a273ca1e579ab573b499).

This correctly handles comments which directly follow a double backslash, such as

```
Line text \\%comment-text
```

The first answer above seems to handle this incorrectly (as if the percent sign were escaped), though I don't have sufficient reputation to comment.

Comment: It indeed seems to handle more subtleties (and is easier to extent).

Comment: there is a bug though. `t_ANY_BACKSLASH` will cause newlines like `\\[2mm]` in a `comment` environment to be returned. Why do you need `ANY`?

Answer (score 3):

The following Perl script should do the trick:  it expects to receive the name of the file you want stripped of comments and prints to console the modified document.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict 'vars';
&MAIN(@ARGV);
sub MAIN {
   my ($filehandle) = @_;
   open FILE, "<$filehandle";
   my @doc = <FILE>;
   close FILE;
   &removeComments(\@doc);

   foreach my $line ( @doc ){
      print $line;
    }
   return 1;
}
sub removeComments {
   my ($docarray) = @_;
   my $isCommentEnvironment = "no";
   my @newdoc;

   foreach my $line ( @{$docarray} ){
      $isCommentEnvironment = "yes" if ( $line =~ /^\\begin{comment}/ );
      if ( $isCommentEnvironment eq "no" ){
     next if ($line =~ /^%/);
     ## Temporarily replace "%" that you want to keep with a dummy string
     ## that does not appear elsewhere in your document.  Then, remove remainder
     ## of lines that still contain "%".
     if ( $line =~ /\\%/){
        $line =~ s/\\%/TMP::PERCENT/g;
        $line =~ s/%.*//;
        $line =~ s/TMP::PERCENT/\\%/g;
      } else {
         $line =~ s/%.*//;
       }
     push @newdoc, $line;
       }
      $isCommentEnvironment = "no" if ( $line =~ /^\\end{comment}/ );
    }

   @{$docarray} = @newdoc;
   return 1;
 }
```

The only thing I'm uncertain about is any contraints on using `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}`.  For example, I don't know whether---like with the `verbatim` environment---you are restricted on what else may appear on those lines.

Answer (score 3):

[pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/index.html) can do this. Running:

```
pandoc latex-comments.tex -o latex-stripped.tex
```

Converts `latex-comments.tex`:

```
I've a LaTeX source.
I'm ready %for submission
%But first I would like
to strip its comments.

So I hope there are
100\% auto
ways to get this done.

\begin{comment}
   Because there are subtle ways to mess it up.
\end{comment}

\begin{verbatim}
        next two lines should not be lost
        % don't lose this line
% this line should stay too
\end{verbatim}
```

to `latex-stripped.tex`:

```
I've a LaTeX source. I'm ready to strip its comments.

So I hope there are 100\% auto ways to get this done.

Because there are subtle ways to mess it up.

\begin{verbatim}
        next two lines should not be lost
        % don't lose this line
% this line should stay too
\end{verbatim}
```

It does remove the `comment` environment, while leaving the contents unaltered. I'm not sure how these environments are used, but it may be possible to keep them with appropriate config settings in pandoc.

Comment: Unfortunately, > pandoc latex-comments.tex -o latex-stripped.tex does more than just strip the comments. It also removes most Latex commands and the preamble.

Comment: @KurtKenner with the -s option it will recreate a stand-alone tex document, with preamble. But I'm not sure how well it incorporates the existing preamble into this :(

Answer (score 3):

(Posting the following as an answer rather than a comment to Ellett's Nov 22 '12 at 15:23 answer because the line breaks in code don't show up in comments.)  Remarking that latex code of the following form:

`here is some text%comment
%comment
, and here is some more text`

is problematic because it compiles as `here is some text, and here is some more text` whereas the stripped code:

`here is some text
, and here is some more text`

compiles as `here is some text , and here is some more text`.

(This goes to the same sort of issue about which user1366204 commented.)

Answer (score 3):

I really like the answer from @Hotschke and put it into a script with the name latex_cleanup.sh.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Removing all comments from a latex source and compile all included source files into one latex document.
# Taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83663/utility-to-strip-comments-from-latex-source
#
# First argument source
# Second arumgent destination
# Example latex_cleanup.sh mytexfile.tex mytexfile_stripped.tex

latexpand --empty-comments "$1" > "$2"
sed -i '/^\s*%/d' "$2"
cat -s "$2" | sponge "$2"
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is extended from @Adam Merberg's answer.

**Modifications:**

1. The original snippet neglect that sometimes `\makeatletter \makeatother` block need the `%` at the end of some lines. Removing those `%` will result in compilation failure.

For example:

```
\makeatletter
   \def\alloc@#1#2#3#4#5%
   {\ifnum\count1#1<#4% make sure there's still room
   \allocationnumber\count1#1
   \global\advance\count1#1\@ne
   \global#3#5\allocationnumber
   \wlog{\string#5=\string#2\the\allocationnumber}%
   \else\ifnum#1<6
   \def\etex@dummy@definition{}% <-- code added
   \begingroup \escapechar\m@ne
   \expandafter\alloc@@\expandafter{\string#2}#5%
   \else\errmessage{No room for a new #2}\fi\fi
    }
 \makeatother
```

The `%` at the end of the 2nd line must be preserved.

2. The original snippet will trim the ending `\n` if there is a line comment, which consequently merge the next line to current line.

For example,

```
\usepackage{foo} % foo package
\usepackage{bar}
\usepackage{baz}
```

will result in

```
\usepackage{foo} \usepackage{bar}
\usepackage{baz}
```

The modified snippet:

```
import ply.lex, argparse, io

# modified from https://gist.github.com/amerberg/a273ca1e579ab573b499

#Usage
# python stripcomments.py input.tex > output.tex
# python stripcomments.py input.tex -e encoding > output.tex

# Modification:
# 1. Preserve "\n" at the end of line comment
# 2. For \makeatletter \makeatother block, Preserve "%" 
#    if it is actually a comment, and trim the line
#    while preserve the "\n" at the end of the line. 
#    That is because remove the % some time will result in
#    compilation failure.

def strip_comments(source):
    tokens = (
                'PERCENT', 'BEGINCOMMENT', 'ENDCOMMENT',
                'BACKSLASH', 'CHAR', 'BEGINVERBATIM',
                'ENDVERBATIM', 'NEWLINE', 'ESCPCT',
                'MAKEATLETTER', 'MAKEATOTHER',
             )
    states = (
                ('makeatblock', 'exclusive'),
                ('makeatlinecomment', 'exclusive'),
                ('linecomment', 'exclusive'),
                ('commentenv', 'exclusive'),
                ('verbatim', 'exclusive')
            )

    # Deal with escaped backslashes, so we don't
    # think they're escaping %
    def t_BACKSLASH(t):
        r"\\\\"
        return t

    # Leaving all % in makeatblock
    def t_MAKEATLETTER(t):
        r"\\makeatletter"
        t.lexer.begin("makeatblock")
        return t

    # One-line comments
    def t_PERCENT(t):
        r"\%"
        t.lexer.begin("linecomment")

    # Escaped percent signs
    def t_ESCPCT(t):
        r"\\\%"
        return t

    # Comment environment, as defined by verbatim package
    def t_BEGINCOMMENT(t):
        r"\\begin\s*{\s*comment\s*}"
        t.lexer.begin("commentenv")

    #Verbatim environment (different treatment of comments within)
    def t_BEGINVERBATIM(t):
        r"\\begin\s*{\s*verbatim\s*}"
        t.lexer.begin("verbatim")
        return t

    #Any other character in initial state we leave alone
    def t_CHAR(t):
        r"."
        return t

    def t_NEWLINE(t):
        r"\n"
        return t

    # End comment environment
    def t_commentenv_ENDCOMMENT(t):
        r"\\end\s*{\s*comment\s*}"
        #Anything after \end{comment} on a line is ignored!
        t.lexer.begin('linecomment')

    # Ignore comments of comment environment
    def t_commentenv_CHAR(t):
        r"."
        pass

    def t_commentenv_NEWLINE(t):
        r"\n"
        pass

    #End of verbatim environment
    def t_verbatim_ENDVERBATIM(t):
        r"\\end\s*{\s*verbatim\s*}"
        t.lexer.begin('INITIAL')
        return t

    #Leave contents of verbatim environment alone
    def t_verbatim_CHAR(t):
        r"."
        return t

    def t_verbatim_NEWLINE(t):
        r"\n"
        return t

    #End a % comment when we get to a new line
    def t_linecomment_ENDCOMMENT(t):
        r"\n"
        t.lexer.begin("INITIAL")

        # Newline at the end of a line comment is presevered.
        return t

    #Ignore anything after a % on a line
    def t_linecomment_CHAR(t):
        r"."
        pass

    def t_makeatblock_MAKEATOTHER(t):
        r"\\makeatother"
        t.lexer.begin('INITIAL')
        return t

    def t_makeatblock_BACKSLASH(t):
        r"\\\\"
        return t

    # Escaped percent signs in makeatblock
    def t_makeatblock_ESCPCT(t):
        r"\\\%"
        return t

    # presever % in makeatblock
    def t_makeatblock_PERCENT(t):
        r"\%"
        t.lexer.begin("makeatlinecomment")
        return t

    def t_makeatlinecomment_NEWLINE(t):
        r"\n"
        t.lexer.begin('makeatblock')
        return t

    # Leave contents of makeatblock alone
    def t_makeatblock_CHAR(t):
        r"."
        return t

    def t_makeatblock_NEWLINE(t):
        r"\n"
        return t

    # For bad characters, we just skip over it
    def t_ANY_error(t):
        t.lexer.skip(1)

    lexer = ply.lex.lex()
    lexer.input(source)
    return u"".join([tok.value for tok in lexer])


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('filename', help = 'the file to strip comments from')
    parser.add_argument('--encoding', '-e', default='utf-8')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    with io.open(args.filename, encoding=args.encoding) as f:
        source = f.read()

    print(strip_comments(source))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The Gist for the code is [here](https://gist.github.com/dzhuang/dc34cdd7efa43e5ecc1dc981cc906c85).

Answer (score 1):

I made a script based on the accepted answer that makes the change in-place, and backs up the old files. Check it out here:

https://gist.github.com/aliparsai/46aad35544e128d72dee6cff44b2af21

```
#!/bin/bash

## Clean-up Comments from Latex Source Files 
## Copyright (c) 2020 Ali Parsai ali@parsai.net
## 
## Dependencies: sponge from moreutils, latexpand, sed, cat, mv, date, cp
## 
## CAUTION: Use version control or backup your files before using this script.
##
## How to use: comment-cleanup.sh TEX_FILE(S)
## 

check_dependency () {
  if type $1 ; then
    echo "==> $1 found."
  else
    date "==> $1 not found. Exitting."
    exit 1
  fi
}

check_dependency mv
check_dependency cp
check_dependency date
check_dependency cat
check_dependency sed
check_dependency sponge
check_dependency latexpand


dt=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
for src in "$@"
  do
    backup="${src}.bak.${dt}"
    cp -v "$src" "$backup"
  done

for src in "$@"
  do
    dest="${src/.tex/-stripped.tex}"
    latexpand --empty-comments --keep-includes "$src" > "$dest"
    sed -i '/^\s*%/d' "$dest"
    cat -s "$dest" | sponge "$dest"
    mv "$dest" "$src"
    echo "==> Processed: $src"
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to strip everything inside the "comment" environment in a file named `'in.tex'` that includes this content:

```
the text above the comment will not be deleted.
\begin{comment}
the content of the solution environment will be deleted (together with any empty line created by the deletion)
\end{comment}
the text below the comment will not be deleted.
```

No bells and whistles Python code based on [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75859649/negate-findall-in-python-re-module):

```
data = open('in.tex').read()
data = re.sub(r'(?m)^\n\\begin({comment})(?:.*\n)+?\\end\1\n', '', data)
```

The output will be:

```
the text above the comment will not be deleted.
the text below the comment will not be deleted.
```

If you want to loop over all files in a given directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import re
# select directory
wd = 'path/to/dir'

for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(wd):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.tex') and '-no-comment' not in filename: 
            basename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
            filepath0 = os.sep.join([dirpath, filename])
            filepath1 = os.sep.join([dirpath, basename+'-no-comment'+ext])
            regex = re.compile(r'(?m)^\n\\begin({comment})(?:.*\n)+?\\end\1\n')
            with open(filepath0) as f0, open(filepath1, 'w') as f1:
                data = f0.read()
                data = re.sub(regex,'', data)
                f1.write(data)
```