Stripping comments in LaTeX
I am struggling to strip comments from a LaTeX file.
I tried the two main answers from this question, but it doesn't work.
Here is a test file:
é %comment


When I run latexpand test.tex > stripped.tex, there is an issue with the encoding of the resulting file, and it doesn't compile to PDF. stripped.tex is as follows:

├⌐ %


When I run arxiv-latex-cleaner \path\to\folder, an error says that arxiv-latex-cleaner is not defined on the PATH: arxiv-latex-cleaner : The term 'arxiv-latex-cleaner' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
I have the folder where arxiv_latex_cleaner.exe is located (namely C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts) to the PATH. I uninstalled and re-installed arxiv-latex-cleaner using pip, both in the Windows prompt and in the Anaconda prompt, to no avail. I still get the same error.

I have Windows 10, Python 3.9 installed through Anaconda, and LaTeX installed via texlive.

Why do you want to do that? Latex will ignore comments during a compile …

try with arxiv-latex-cleaner.exe. Imho unless you have set a variable, the powershell needs the extension.

@UlrikeFischer Same error.

@MS-SPO I want to strip comments as these are not intended for dissemination, contrary to my .tex file.

@bixiou Try with the full path to the .exe?

Ad 1: In the multibyte character set which forms the utf-8 encoding the character é is represented by the two bytes  0xC3 and 0xA9 while in single byte character sets like IBM437/cp437 and IBM863/cp863 and IBM865/cp865 the byte 0xC3 represents the character ├ and the byte 0xA9 represents the character ⌐. The readme of latexpand at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexpand says the --out-encoding FMT by default is byte and not utf-8,  thus as --out-encoding FMT you may need to explicitly specify  'encoding(UTF-8)'.

Ad 2: Probably just adding to PATH is not sufficient but you need to add the directory to PYTHONPATH as well - see https://superuser.com/a/1372799.

Ad 1: latexpand --out-encoding 'encoding(UTF-8)' --empty-comments test.tex > stripped.tex produces the same problem.
AD 2: How can I change the PYTHONPATH on Windows? export is not recognized by the command prompt. @UlrichDiez

I've posted an answer to your linked question using latexindent.pl https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83663/utility-to-strip-comments-from-latex-source/716953#716953

@bixiou PYTHONPATH on Windows - probably you can do the four steps described under Permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH.

@UlrichDiez It still doesn't work after adding an example.pth file with the right path in it in the indicated folder.

I have circumvented the issue with a simple manual solution.
On VS Code (and probably many other .tex editors), one can do that using three simple regex (Ctrl + H, tick .*, copy/paste the strings blow, and Replace all):

Save end-of-line %:
Replace
(.+)%\n
by
$1SAVEDXXX\n.

Remove comments:
Replace
(?<!\\)%.*\n
by
%.

Put back end-of-line %:
Replace
SAVEDXXX
by
%.


Note that we prevent the regex from matching \% using (?<!\\)%.
Also note that the procedure would also works with only step 2, though it would merge two lines into one (for lines ending with %, which is frequent in LaTeX code). This would not affect LaTeX functioning (unless I missed special cases), but would be less visually pleasant.

(this is the 4th version)
Save this as file stripper.tex
% macro to sanitize  catcodes, making space and % active
\def\stringregime{%
    \catcode`\\ \active % to catch \%
    \catcode`\{ 12
    \catcode`\} 12
    \catcode`\# 12
    \catcode32 \active
    \catcode`\~ 12
    \catcode`\% \active
}%

% active space gives normal space
\begingroup
\catcode32\active\xdef {\string }%
\endgroup

% this is to handle \%. We take advantage that the active \ will expand in a
% context where one is certain there is an added \empty token, so it is safe
% to fetch a #1 token and test for it being the (active) %.  And the { and }
% will be catcode 12, no unbracing is possible.
\begingroup
\catcode`\% \active
\def\gobble#1{}\xdef\backslashchar{\expandafter\gobble\string\\}
\lccode`~`\\\lowercase{\gdef~}#1{\backslashchar\ifx#1%\expandafter\string\fi#1}
\endgroup

% percent char
\begingroup
% the \empty delimiter will be added manually by \handlelines
\catcode`\%\active
\xdef%#1\empty{\string%}
\endgroup

\def\removeEOLspacechar#1 {\def\fileline{#1}}
\def\bracedpar{\par}

% main loop macro
\def\handlelines{%
  \ifeof\infile 
  \else
  \read\infile to \fileline
  % remove the EOL space from \fileline before outputting it
  % If TeX replaces an empty line by \par in input there is no space
  % token only the \par token.
  \ifx\fileline\bracedpar\def\fileline{}\else
      \expandafter\removeEOLspacechar\fileline
  \fi
  \immediate\write\outfile{\fileline\empty}% delimiter for active %
    \expandafter\handlelines
  \fi
}

% loop launch
\def\DoIt{%
  \begingroup
  \stringregime
  \handlelines
  \endgroup
}

% file auxiliaries
\newread\infile
\newwrite\outfile
\immediate\write128{}
\message{filename to strip of comments: }\read-1to\theinfile
% clean up trailing space
\def\cleanuptrailingspace#1 \par{\def\theinfile{#1}}
\expandafter\cleanuptrailingspace\theinfile\par
%
  \openin\infile\theinfile\relax
  \immediate\openout\outfile\theinfile-out

\DoIt

\immediate\write128{output written to \theinfile-out USE AT OWN RISK}
  \immediate\closein\infile
  \immediate\closeout\outfile
\bye


Usage
Please have the file to be stripped in the same working repertory where the above code has been saved as file stripper.tex.
Issue etex stripper on command line, you are then prompted for a filename.  Input it (you may drop the .tex) then eTeX produces the output in a new file in the working repertory.
This process identifies all %'s and, except if arising as \% will remove all following tokens, keeping the lead % itself.
All (non trailing, TeX itself trims them out) spaces are preserved, no extra space is added.  No empty line is removed or added, apart from an empty line at end of file.
Use at own risk.  Always check output.

Haven't tried yet but thank you! Couldn't you adapt it to leave end-of-line "%"?

@bixiou Updated.

Haven't tried but if it doesn't handle \%, it is of limited use.

Latest version handles \%.

Note that this can not handle properly contexts where the catcode of % gets modified, for example the \ifx#1%\expandafter\string\fi#1} core TeX code in stripper.tex itself would become in output \ifx#1%.  No tool can solve this without parsing the TeX code itself and understand it.  Check unravel source for a glimpse of the complexity of such task.
