Hide comments with Mathcha
I'm using the website Mathcha.io to edit figures in Tikz more easily.
Does anyone know how to hide comments they give you with the code ? There are so many of them it becomes hard to see it clear.
When you "Export selection to LaTeX", hence when they give you the code you want to copy in your LaTeX document, there is many lines just to comment drawings :

Is there an option on the website to get rid of all that ?

Please can you explain better your question?

Use only copy to clipboard. After use Ctrl+V  to glue the TikZ code.

Thanks for you interest, but I've already tried that. It puts the exact same text in the clipboard (with the numerous comments).

The comments there are always.

@LouisLascaud You can use tools like the ones listed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83663/utility-to-strip-comments-from-latex-source to remove the comments after you've inserted the code.

Thanks for the tip !
